# ЯндексКарта Открыть балун по id

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Помогите пожалуйста, на карту метки добавляются с помощью ObjectManager и кластеризуются. Задача после клика на ссылку с id балуна, перемещать карту таким образом, чтобы балун оказался видимым и открывать его. Как закрывать вопросов нет.

```
        $("#lll").bind('click', function () {
            if (objectManager.objects.balloon.isOpen(162)) {
                objectManager.objects.balloon.close();
            } else {
                objectManager.objects.balloon.open(162);
            }
        });
```

В коде выше, 162 балун и открывается и закрывается, НО если карта не приближена к балуну (т.е. этот балун сгруппирован с другими) то открывается он в таком ужасном виде https://yadi.sk/i/MUt1iKP83XmDiD Видимо надо использовать autoPan но что то не пойму как его прикрутить.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Сделал так...

```
myMap.setCenter(coordinates,zoom, {checkZoomRange: true}).then(function () {
    objectManager.objects.balloon.open(id);
});
```